# How to control when Maya executes scriptJobs?

Tags: python, unit-testing, maya

I'm trying to test a library that uses Maya `scriptJobs` and re-dispatches them as Qt Signals.  I'm running into a problem where I can't test whether a signal is being properly re-dispatched because the Maya scriptJobs don't appear to run until after Maya has completed all the test functions.

This test will fail, as the handler isn't called before the `call_count` is checked.

```
from mock import Mock
from maya import cmds

def test_func():
    cmds.currentTime(1)
    handler = Mock()
    cmds.scriptJob(e=('timeChanged', handler))
    # This should trigger the scriptJob, and thus, call the handler
    # but it doesn't until all python is finished executing.
    cmds.currentTime(2)
    assert handler.call_count == 1
```

If I define the handler as a global variable, and then do a two-step test where I run `test_one()` by itself, let it complete, and then run `test_two()`, it works.

```
handler = Mock()
def test_one():
    cmds.currentTime(1)
    cmds.scriptJob(e=('timeChanged', handler)
    cmds.currentTime(2)

def test_two():
    assert handler.call_count == 1
```

Is there anyway to force Maya to process `scriptJobs` *now*, instead of waiting until all the python is finished executing?  Or maybe there is just a better way of testing this?

Answer (score 1):

The scriptJobs won't be processed until the maya main loop resumes, which is after the script completes.  If you want it to be synchronous you'll need to call the functions directly.  You can try invoking `utils.processIdleEvents()` to see if that will force the scriptJobs to fire in-line but I'm not sure that's a good simulation of whatever you are testing.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, `processIdleEvents()` doesn't seem to force it, might have to rethink how I test it.